# selenium rc to open a Google search page and search for the text and print all the url which has that text present in it

Tags: selenium-rc

my requirement is, I want to search a text in google and on the result page, find all the links which have that text present and later to click on that link.
description of requirement in steps:
Step1)open google homepage
step2)search a keyword
step3)on result page print all the links which contain the search keyword
step4)click on the link contain the search keyword

so would like to know is there any way to achieve this by selenium or any other tool,detail description is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C# console application which uses Selenium WebDriver.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // The keyword you would like to search for
            string keyword = "stack overflow";

            // Step 1
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com/";

            // Step 2
            IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
            input.SendKeys(keyword);
            input.Submit();

            // Wait for page to load
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            // Fill a list with the resulting links
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            ICollection<IWebElement> searchResults = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/h3/a"));
            foreach (IWebElement resultLink in searchResults)
            {
                string link = resultLink.GetAttribute("href");
                results.Add(link);
            }

            // Output each link and click on each link
            foreach (string link in results)
            {
                // Step 3
                Console.WriteLine(link);

                // Step 4
                driver.Url = link;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,but I want to do this in java, so it would be really helpful if you explain how to Fill a list with the resulting links in java as I am very new to programming language.

Comment: That's not the question you asked...  In Java you could use an ArrayList.

Comment: sorry for bothering, I have completed it using array! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This code will search a a text in google and collect all the link on the result page!

```
package com.example.tests;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
    public class CopyOfsource {
        private static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {


            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.print("***********test**************");
            driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=test&oq=test&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1452727l1453164l0l1453839l7l5l0l0l0l0l278l1194l2-

    5l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2bcac73b2935e785&biw=1366&bih=643");

            List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/h3/a"));

            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            int num=element.size();
            System.out.println("***************Report Created is in Location "+ num + "/n");
            for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                WebElement resultlink = element.get(i);
                String link = resultlink.getAttribute("href");
                results.add(link);
                System.out.println("***************Report Created is in Location : " + link);  

            }




            driver.close();



        }}
```